# Have I over-installed MySQL?

Tags: server, mysql

I ran the following from the terminal:

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client

I then checked to see if MySQL was running:

> sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql

I saw something similar to this:

> tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                LISTEN      2556/mysqld

I knew I also needed the MySQL Workbench, so I went to the software center and downloaded the Workbench.

When I checked to see if MySQL was running, I saw the following

```
$ sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      1003/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 localhost:52515         localhost:mysql         ESTABLISHED 3167/mysql-workbenc
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:52514         TIME_WAIT   -              
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:52516         ESTABLISHED 1003/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 localhost:52516         localhost:mysql         ESTABLISHED 3167/mysql-workbenc
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:52515         ESTABLISHED 1003/mysqld
```

**My question is, have I over-installed some portion of MySQL?** I just want to take care of what I need to, prior to going into some more development.

Answer (score 0):

Well for me it appears like this:

```
cyrex@cyrex:~$ sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
[sudo] password for cyrex: 
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      1294/mysqld
```

What I would do is first (Am assuming you do not have any information in the database yet):

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

then

```
ps -e| grep mysql
```

If anything mysql related appears there kill it:

```
sudo killall mysqld
```

Double check to see if it still there with the `ps` command above. If it is then kill it:

`sudo kill -9 PID` where the PID is the ID of the process. Then double check again, if there is no more mysql process running around then:

`sudo service mysql start`

You actually reminded me of something that happened a long time ago (Ubuntu 9.10 I think). It was the same thing but about 20 more processes.

Comment: Interesting. Ok, Luis, thank you. When I get a moment, I will look into these suggestions. I appreciate this, and may have a follow-up if I get stuck. ~David

Answer (score 0):

What would "over-installed" mean? Servers processes are in the business of opening multiple, simultaneous connections; that's kinda what "server" means.

Even network intensive programs like browsers have multiple connections:

```
$ sudo netstat -ntap | grep chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.4:33424   example:80       ESTABLISHED 1579/chrome     
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.4:59647   example:80       ESTABLISHED 1579/chrome     
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.4:37446   example:5222     ESTABLISHED 1579/chrome     
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.4:48011   example:443      ESTABLISHED 1579/chrome     
... 20 more connections omitted for brevity ...
```

Sockets are cheap, especially when they aren't busy.

Comment: In the comparison of the netstat check before installing the GUI Workbench and after. Humbly, I do not know if I understand enough about the MySQL install to know if the server install and the Workbench install overlapped anything such as connections. I am glad that you mentioned what you did about servers being in the business of opening multiple/simultaneous connections. That makes sense to me. I just did not think that would be happening as early in the process as it did, but I plead my ignorance on the totality of understanding. At least I can rule out an ititial mistake. Thank you msw!

Comment: @David Well, the workbench holds open a socket to your server as part of its operation. It's also not uncommon for processes to have sockets open to themselves for various reasons.